# Any way to intruct MsTest when to run a Test Method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

Is there a way or approach like a method decorator or attribute for a test method that can say for example:

**"Run Method C Before running Method B"**

So basically you are creating a dependancy between C and B. I know tests are better off being atomic and should be but sometimes in it's better to keep your tests small and to the point. It makes sense not run a 'RemoveItem' test method when the item it is looking for is simply not there.

Most people would add the item before hand and then test to see if they can remove - '***All In the same test***'. I don't like this approach and want to make my tests smaller, more to to point and more atomic as possible.

Comment: It sounds to me you are explicitly trying to make your tests *less* atomic, not more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, you dont want interdependencies between your test. If you are not comfortable having an "Add" before the "Remove" in your remove test, thus testing the Add method in the wrong place, then I recommend using testInitialize to setup some objects the tests can act on. I *do* however recommend the practice of actually running Add before you run Remove, in the test of Remove.

```
[Testclass]
public class TestStacks
{
  private Stack<string> emptyStack;
  private Stack<string> singleItemStack;

  [TestInitialize]
  public void Setup()
  {
    singleItemStack = new Stack<string>();
    singleItemStack.Push("Item");
    emptyStack = new Stack<string>();
  }

  [TestMethod]
  public void TestPush()
  {       
    emptyStack.Push("Added");
    Assert.AreEqual(1, emptyStack.Count);
  }

  [TestMethod]
  public void TestRemove()
  {       
    singleItemStack.Pop();
    Assert.AreEqual(0, singleItemStack.Count);
  }  

  [TestMethod]
  [ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
  public void TestPopFromEmpty()
  {       
    emptyStack.Pop();
  }  

}
```

Comment: TY, yeah I guess. I am using them as it is but I thought it would be nice to see if there was an attribute that kind of did this without having to create TestInitialise methods. Still though I suppose I do have my answer I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have some item added before testing removal, then best place to add item is `arrange` part of removal test. This will make context of removal test clear.

But DRY principle also works here - you can move addition logic to separate helper method. Then call it twice - when testing addition, and when arranging context for removal:

```
[Testclass]
public class Tests
{        
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestAddition()
    {
        AddItem();
        // Assert addition           
    }   

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestRemoval()
    {
       AddItem();
       // Remove item
       // Assert removal
    } 

    private void AddItem()
    {
       // Add item           
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm ... I see what you mean but you gotta admit, an attriibute that clearly labels the dependency placed on a method is a much slicker solution right?

Comment: Maybe slicker, but how will you know in which state addition test left your SUT? One item was added, or two? In which state your SUT after executing `TearDown`? In which state your SUT after executing `Setup`? It looks like you are trying to test two things at once, but splitting one big test method in two tightly coupled methods. Thats why test-linking feature was not added to test frameworks.